# How to import gltf 3d models in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, 3d, gltf

Does anyone know a good way of importing **gltf 3d models** in Flutter?

I tried using:

`model_viewer`,
`flutter_cube`,
`babylonjs_viewer`

but wasn't able to load a gltf file with any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The lightly documented [three_dart_jsm](https://github.com/wasabia/three_dart_jsm) repository has a class "GLTFLoader" that is able to load gltf/glb files.

For viewing the gltf, I would recommend [three_dart](https://github.com/wasabia/three_dart) by the same author.

Answer (score 0):

Model_viexer_plus does import a gltf model and displays it, i returned the gltf file using a route from my backend, and used that route as entry into ModelViewer url and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flutter_3d_controller package. It works with (`glb`, `gltf`, `fbx`, `obj`) file formats.

Here's the link to the package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_3d_controller.

p.s. The rendering of 3D models might not work on some laptops, maybe because of the graphics resolution.
It might be because of this that you were not able to render 3D models. I also faced the same issue, as I was not able to render 3D models on my laptop, but I was able to render them on other computer with high-end configurations with the same code.